# Python keep anchors when modifying value in Yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a yaml file with anchors and aliases similar to below one:

```yaml
dev:
    value1: &dev-value1 "value1"
    value2: &dev-value2 "value2"

test:
    value1: *dev-value1
    value2: *dev-value2
```

I would like to change the value for key dev/value1 but also to preserve the anchor.

With a simple script:

```py
import ruamel.yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

with open("test.eyaml") as eyaml_file:
    data = yaml.load(eyaml_file)

    data["dev"]["value1"] = "new_value"
with open("new.eyaml", "w") as new_eyaml_file:
    yaml.dump(data, new_eyaml_file)
```

It changes the value but the anchor is now missing and the modified file looks like below:

```yaml
dev:
  value1: new_value
  value2: &dev-value2 value2

test:
  value1: &dev-value1 value1
  value2: *dev-value2
```

And I would like it be looks like this:

```yaml
dev:
    value1: &dev-value1 "new_value"
    value2: &dev-value2 "value2"

test:
    value1: *dev-value1
    value2: *dev-value2
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: If you add the `ruamel.yaml` tag to a question (if appropriate of course), I get notified automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously `ruamel.yaml` can preserve the anchor, otherwise it would not show up
after round-trip (e.g. for `data['dev']['value2']`).
But you are assigning a string to `data['dev']['value1']`, while after loading your YAML that is not a string.
Instead it is a subclass, still behaving like a string (a `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.PlainScalarString` instance), which
holds the anchor and other information necessary for a more faithful round-trip).

However that instance is still immutable, so you will need to find any values in your data-structure
that have the same `id` as the original and update those as well:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
dev:
    value1: &dev-value1 "value1"
    value2: &dev-value2 "value2"

test:
    value1: *dev-value1
    value2: *dev-value2
"""

def change_all_old_ids(d, old_id, new_value):
    """ this doesn't handle anchored keys """
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if id(v) == old_id:
                d[k] = new_value
            else:
                change_all_old_ids(v, old_id, new_value)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for idx, elem in enumerate(d):
            if id(elem) == old_id:
                d[idx] = new_value
            else:
                change_all_old_ids(elem, old_id, new_value)

    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
old_value = data['dev']['value1']

data['dev']['value1'] = new_value = type(old_value)('new_value')
new_value.yaml_set_anchor(old_value.anchor.value, always_dump=True)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print('+='*10)
change_all_old_ids(data, id(old_value), new_value)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
dev:
  value1: &dev-value1 new_value
  value2: &dev-value2 value2

test:
  value1: &dev-value1 value1
  value2: *dev-value2
+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
dev:
  value1: &dev-value1 new_value
  value2: &dev-value2 value2

test:
  value1: *dev-value1
  value2: *dev-value2
```

I included the dump before calling `change_all_old_ids` to show what
will happen if you wouldn't call that function.